# How do I prevent execution of code in a "for" loop?

Tags: javascript

I have a loop:

```
for (var language in locales) {
    if(language == 'en') //go on to next language and do not do code below
```

I wish to prevent code inside the for from executing in certain conditions.

I've tried `break;` but this stops the entire loop from continuing on to the next language.

How can I prevent code from executing below the if statement but still maintain a loop?

Comment: How about `continue`?

Comment: so you don't want to break out of the loop. You just want to skip to the next iteration. That's a different thing..

Answer (score 7):

You need to use `continue` for skipping current iteration of a loop and continue with the next iteration.

Answer (score 2):

Use-continue

```
for (var language in locales) {
    if(language == 'en')
       continue;
    statement;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively to `continue`, you can just use an `if` statement:

```
for (var language in locales) if(language !== 'en') {
  // ...
}
```